# Console Error Message for removing Elements

Tags: javascript

I got a function for removing elements from the site. When i click the "ok" button the console tells me "removeElements is not defined"...?! But in my opinion everything is done right.

Here is the code:

```
function showPic(obj, yes)
    {
        var obj = (yes) ? obj : this;
        if(!isTimeRunning)
        {
            isTimeRunning = true;
            chronoId = setInterval(function() { chronometro() }, 1000);
            pointers[game] = chronoId;
        }
        if(!waitASecond)
        {
            if(!imagesInGame.isInArray(obj))
            {
                return;
            }
            if(!clicks.length)
            {
                clicks[0] = obj;
                if(!openedImages.isInArray(obj))
                {
                    notOpenedImages.deleteElementByValue(obj.divNum, 'divNum');
                }
                obj.firstChild.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else
            {
                if(clicks[0].divNum == obj.divNum)
                    return;
                clicks[1] = obj;
                if(!openedImages.isInArray(obj))
                {
                    openedImages.push(obj);
                    notOpenedImages.deleteElementByValue(obj.divNum, 'divNum');
                }
                obj.firstChild.style.display = 'none';
                waitASecond = true;

                checkIdentity();
                document.getElementById('numberOfTries' + game).value = allPlayers[player]['failures'];
            }
        }
    }

    function showPicOnclick()
    {
        if(humanPlayer)
            showPic(this, true);
    }
    function checkIdentity()
        {
            if(clicks[0].imageNum == clicks[1].imageNum)
            {
                countPairs();
                imagesInGame.deleteElementByValue(clicks[0].imageNum, 'imageNum');
                openedImages.deleteElementByValue(clicks[0].imageNum, 'imageNum');
                addElement('match_div_one_'+clicks[1].imageNum, "img");
                addElement('match_div_two_'+clicks[1].imageNum, 'Inhalt1');
                addElement('match_div_three_'+clicks[1].imageNum, 'Inhalt1');
                addElement('match_div_button_'+clicks[1].imageNum, '<button onclick="removeElements()">OK</button>');

                /*alert(messages[clicks[1].imageNum]);  */

                gotLastPair = player;
                waitASecond = false;
                clicks.clean();
                checkForGameEnd();
            }
            else
            {
                allPlayers[player]['failures']++;
                turnId = setTimeout(function() { hidePics() }, timeout);
            }
        }

    function removeElement(divNum) {
            var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);
            olddiv.parentNode.removeChild(olddiv);
        }

        function removeElements() {
            removeElement('match_div_one_'+clicks[1].imageNum);
            removeElement('match_div_two_'+clicks[1].imageNum);
            removeElement('match_div_three_'+clicks[1].imageNum);
            removeElement('match_div_button_'+clicks[1].imageNum);
        }
```

Comment: Try to place `removeElements()` before `checkIdentity()`.

Comment: doesn´t work, i tried this right now. It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: removeElements is not defined" (1) "onclick" (2)

Comment: Where is that code located? If the browser thinks it's not defined, then it's not defined **globally** - possibly that code you posted is inside some sort of "load" or "ready" handler, which would make all the functions local to that function.

Comment: i added some code where the checkidentity function is used. the removeElements function is at the end of my js, while the rest is somewhere in the middle. The console shows me the error in my HTML which is somehow confusing. It says "name.html:1"